# Get items from JSONArray and show it one by one in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout

I read my json in a class JSONParser. My parsing works very well. I can have each element I want.

Here is my **JSONFILE** :

```
"interface":{
"View":[
{
    "id":"0",
    "type":"Simple",
    "Label":[
        {
    "text":"bonjour comment ca va ?",
    "position_x":"200",
        "position_y":"400"
        },
        {
        "text":"coucou les amis",
        "position_x":"200",
        "position_y":"200"
        }
    ],
```

I have a problem. I can set "text", "position_x", "position_y" in my logcat. But i want to put that value as paramater of a TextView to get a dynamically app.

Here is my **JSONParser.java** :

```
public class JSONParser extends Activity {

 private JSONObject myjsonobj = null;
    //  Map<String, String> jsonresult = new HashMap<String, String>();

// private JSONArray myinterface = null;

// ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> labelList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    public JSONParser(String file) throws IOException {
        file = "assets/JsonTest.txt";

        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                    "UTF-8"));
            String temp;
            while ((temp = buf.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(temp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }

        try {
            Log.e("Parser JSON", "Parser JSON OK");
            myjsonobj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("OBJSON", myjsonobj.toString());
    }



    public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams setPosition(int positionX,int positionY)   {


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.addRule(positionX);
        params.addRule(positionY);
        return params;
    }

    public void classicSetLabel(JSONArray myArrayLabel, ClassicView classicView, Context context) throws JSONException {

        Log.e("@@@@@WARNING TEXTLABEL :", "classicSetLabelErreur1");

        Log.e("@@@@@WARNING TEXTLABEL :", "classicSetLabelErreur2");
        for (int i = 0; i < myArrayLabel.length(); i++) {
            Log.e("CLASSICVIEW", classicView.toString());
            TextView myTextView = new TextView(context);
            LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(context);


//              classicView.addContentView(myLayout, setPosition(100, 100));
            myTextView.append(myArrayLabel.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));

            classicView.view.addView(myTextView, setPosition(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL));
            Log.e("@@@@@WARNING TEXTLABEL :", myArrayLabel.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
            Log.e("@@@@@WARNING TEXTPOS_X", myArrayLabel.getJSONObject(i).getString("position_x"));
            Log.e("@@@@@WARNING TEXTPOS_Y", myArrayLabel.getJSONObject(i).getString("position_y"));
            //classicView.addContentView(myLayout, setPosition(0, 0));
        }
}

    public ClassicView getClassicViewWithId(int id, Context context) throws JSONException {
         JSONArray myView = myjsonobj.getJSONObject("interface").getJSONArray("View");                  
        for (int i = 0; i < myView.length(); i++) {
            if (myView.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id") == id) {
                Log.e("IDVIEW", myView.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                ClassicView myClassicView = new ClassicView(myView.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));

                //classicSetLabel(myView.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Label"), myClassicView, context);
                return myClassicView;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have ma LinearLayout programmatically charged. I can create a TextView inside but I don't know how to do that with my JSON file. Maybe I need to use ArrayList ? or something like that ? Here is my LinearLayout programmatically

**ClassicView.java** :

```
public class ClassicView extends Activity {

public int myid;
public  LinearLayout view;
JSONArray myArrayLabel;
ClassicView classicView;
JSONParser jParser;
Context context;    
public ClassicView() {

}
     public ClassicView(int id){
         super();
         myid = id;
     }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linearlayout);

        view = new LinearLayout(this);
//          TextView mytv = new TextView(this);
//          mytv.setText("SALUT ");
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
//          view.addView(mytv, lp);
        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java** :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    JSONParser jParser = null;
    try {
        jParser = new JSONParser("JsonTest.txt");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ClassicView view = jParser.getClassicViewWithId(0, MainActivity.this);
        //Log.e("idVIEWMAIN :", msg)
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, view.getClass());
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I just don't know how to set my TextView with json  in my LinearLayout. Somebody have an idea what i am doing wrong or can help me please ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Please format your code properly, it's difficult to read.

Comment: You're making your life awfully complicated. Why don't you use a Json deserializer such as Google gson?

Comment: @NathanZ I never used it

Comment: time to start... It takes your json into a java object in 2 lines of code

Comment: I've seen some performance metrics on GSON - FlexJSON and Jackson Mapper are also easy to use APIs for converting POJO into JSON, and have better overall speed/performance than GSON.